# JOIN with ORDER or MAX()?

Tags: mysql, sql

Example.
I need to get list of posts and match 1 comment to each one (newest, oldest or most rated).

Are there any suggestions?

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN comments c
ON p.id = c.post_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

And now I need to set, which one from comments (top, newest or oldest) must be matched with post. 
But I really don't know how to.

Comment: Can you give query then we can help more which you have tried.

Comment: You're using MySQL so you probably need to use a correlated subquery. SQL Server you could use `(CROSS|OUTER) APPLY` with `SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY whatever`

Comment: Here. Thanks for waching

Comment: ta.speot.is, I think it must be some way not to use subquery..

Comment: ta.speot.is, can I beg you to write an example, please?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks information to diagnose the problem. Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 0):

Newest:

```
SELECT MAX(с.created) ........
FROM comments c
GROUP BY c.post_id
```

Oldest:

```
SELECT MIN(с.created) ........
FROM comments c
GROUP BY c.post_id
```

Most rated:

```
SELECT MAX(с.rating) ........
FROM comments c
GROUP BY c.post_id
```